# Sending $_GET variables to templateUrl using ngRoute

Tags: angularjs

Im currently switching my application to a Single Page Application. Im having some problems configuring my ngRoute.
What I want is to send a ID to the templateUrl using ?id=.

How do I do that?
This my code:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/testing/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/testing.php?id=:id'
    });
}]);
```

It now passes ":id" as the value for ID. Which is obvious, but how do I make it send the ":id" passed in the URL?

For example:

**/testing/45**

Becomes:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/testing/45', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/testing.php?id=45'
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`$routeProvider` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) the `templateUrl` can also be a function:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/testing/:id', {
        templateUrl: function(params) {
            return 'templates/testing.php?id=' + params.id;
        }
    });
}]);
```